# Separate figure with 2 subfigures within the same document with two columns

Tags: floats, two-column

I would like to know if anyone knows how the implementation of something like what I show in the next image could be carried out.

[image]

The idea would be that both figures are within the same but that they can be separated by the sub-tags (a) and (b) to which I should be able to refer anywhere in the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do that with `subcaption`, but "possible" does not mean "good idea":

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,lipsum,microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

The figure ``(\subref{a})'' is really the subfigure \ref{a} 
from  figure \ref{c} but is not with subfigure \ref{b}, 
and there are not a true caption here, just to confuse you.
    
\lipsum[1][1-1] 
  \begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{}\label{a}
\end{subfigure}
%\caption{xxx}
 \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[t]
   \ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\subcaption{}\label{b}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{xxx}\label{c}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2-4] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works :D